# What is a better way to program this application?

Tags: java, optimization, variable-assignment

I am doing an assignment for my class, and I am trying to display something like the following image: [image: 5 kids and 5 scores]

The thing is, I am new new to java and I have no idea how to make a nested loop like this work without hard coding every loop. My question is... How can I make this code more efficient, and dynamic?

import java.util.Scanner;
public class BarChart {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int score3;
    int score4;
    int score5;
    final String PROMPT = "Enter points scored by ";

    System.out.print(PROMPT + " Art >>>");
    score1 = scn.nextInt();

    System.out.print(PROMPT + " Bob >>>");
    score2 = scn.nextInt();

    System.out.print(PROMPT + " Cal >>>");
    score3 = scn.nextInt();

    System.out.print(PROMPT + " Dan >>>");
    score4 = scn.nextInt();

    System.out.print(PROMPT + " Eli >>>");
    score5 = scn.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Art ");

    for (int y = 1; y <= score1; y++)
    {
            System.out.print(" *");

    }
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.print("Bob ");

    for (int y = 1; y <= score2; y++)
    {
            System.out.print(" *");

    }
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.print("Cal ");

    for (int y = 1; y <= score3; y++)
    {
            System.out.print(" *");

    }
    System.out.print("\n");


    System.out.print("Dan ");

    for (int y = 1; y <= score4; y++)
    {
            System.out.print(" *");

    }
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.print("Eli ");

    for (int y = 1; y <= score5; y++)
    {
            System.out.print(" *");

    }





}
```

}

Comment: Yes. Use an appropriate *data-structure* such as a [List](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+list+tutorial) (an "ordered sequence of values that can grow"), an array ("an ordered sequence with a fixed size"), or even a Map ("mapping a set of keys to values"). Using one of these basic data-structures, or a derivative of such, should be done [almost] every time there are "[many] repeated variables", especially when the variable names add in numbers :}

Comment: Make a class that holds `name` and `score`, then populate the list with your names and loop over it to store scores and again to display scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all the names and scores into arrays. Then you can use for loops to loop through the arrays:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] scores = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0};
String[] names = new String[] {"Art", "Bob", "Cal", "Dan", "Eli"};
final String PROMPT = "Enter points scored by ";

// a loop to ask for input
// you can treat these loops as saying "for each name in the names array, do this..."
for(int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    // in the first iteration "names[i]" will be "Art", second iteration
    // will be "Bob", and so on
    System.out.print(PROMPT + names[i] + " >>>");
    // set the corresponding score
    scores[i] = scn.nextInt();
}

// another loop to print a bar chart
for(int i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
    System.out.print(names[i] + " ");

    for (int y = 1; y <= scores[i]; y++) {
        System.out.print(" *");

    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list that contains a map, the list will save the user entries and the map will contain the Name(Key) and the points(Value).